# Hudson - separate SVN dir and build dir?

Tags: hudson

Is it possible in a Hudson job to specify a different Source directory to poll to the directory in which a build is run ?
I've used Hudson successfully to enforce compilation success in java projects.
An SVN directory is polled every say 5 mins and an ant target specified - the errant programmer getting emailed in the event of failures.
However in every case the ant build.xml happened to reside in the same directory as the SVN directory being polled.

Basically I am trying to apply the same system to an Oracle database build.
There are multiple directories to watch (schema, static data, stored procs etc and an upstream / downstream order).
However the ant build script resides several directories above the directories I wish to poll.

I guess the solution is I must create multiple ant build.xmls one for each database component and I assume a separate Hudson job for each ?
I wondered was there a better way of doing this.
Best Rgds
Peter

Comment: It doesnt appear to be possible to have separate poll and build directories per se. Referring to ../../ in the build configuration merely brings you up to the hudson workspace. I had to configure separate Hudson jobs above and separate builds

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the project from the highest level and configure your build steps to execute the various steps in the the sub folder as you would do it manually. As long as everything needed is in the workspace you can build whatever is in there in the top level as well as sub folders.